# If condition as a Stopping Criterion in a Python For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I wish to write a `for` loop such that the stopping criterion is that which satisfies a difference between two consecutive elements in a list. The list is appended from the `for` loop as shown in the code below:

```
m, n = 100, 4
counter1 = []
tol = 1e-8

x_not = np.zeros(n)
for iterate in range(100):
    for rows in range(m):
        y = My_func(x_not, rows)
        x_not = y
        counter1.append(norm(x_not))
        if counter1[i-1] - counter1[i] < tol:
            break
```

I wish the `for` loop to stop whenever any two consecutive elements is less than `tol`. I need someone to help implement this code in Python. `My_func` is a predefined function.

Comment: Which for loop are you referring to?

Comment: Hi, MaliMali, what have you tried so far? You'll get a much better response from the community if you show what you've tried and you have a specific question.

Comment: I actually included a sample code in my post

Comment: `counter1[-1]` will _always_  give you the last element of `counter1`. `counter1[-2]` will give you the last-but-one. Because you append to `counter1`, the last element is what you just appended. The last-but-one is the one you appended before that.

Comment: Also, you can only compare two elements from your list after the second element has been appended.

Comment: Maybe you could insert this code into a function and call return.

Comment: @Pranav Honsangadi No it does not. I actually wanted a situation where the difference between any two elements of the list _counter1_ is less than _tol_

Comment: Can you give an example of an input, and show what values would cause the desired output?

Comment: @damon counter1 =  [0.1, 1.2, 1.22222222, 1.22222221] I wish to make the loop to stop in this case when i = 3 since counter1[3] - counter1[2] < tol

Comment: What doesn't work with your current code?

Comment: @Prune The error I got was: 'i is not defined'

Comment: You need to define `i` for that expression to work; that is not a difficult problem.  Since you're working with only the last two elements, why do you need the entire list and a custom index?

Comment: @Prune Because the list is always updated with _append_ from the loop

Comment: You need only the two most recent values, not the entire history.  You don't need an index variable to get the last two values.

Comment: @Prune Thank you. I get the logic now

Comment: @Pranav Honsangadi Thanks for your earlier comment. I later realised the logic in your post.